# remove linebreaks \n for create an caldav event

Tags: php, caldav

I have a textarea, where I write down the following text:

[image]

Than I submit it and makes an echo of this value (echo $_POST['myText']):
It looks like:

```
This is my text, with a new line and another.
```

Without any line breaks. That is good - I need this text without line breaks.
Than I take this value and send it my function, which need this value to create an event in my calendar.

But the result looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Synology//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20210724T174910
LAST-MODIFIED:20210724T174910
DTSTAMP:20210724T174910
UID:20210724T174910-13ea995f
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY:My Event
TRANSP:
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20210728T180000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20210728T190000
DESCRIPTION:This is my text\,
\nwith a new line 
\nand another.
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VCALENDAR
```

Why are there the line breaks available (`\n`) ?
How can I remove them ?

I tried something like this:

```
$myText = str_replace(array('\r', '\n'), '', $_POST['myText']);
```

But it will gives every time the same result like above.
I don't know why :/

Comment: "_makes an echo of this value_" On CLI or via webserver? They'll show on cli but not via webserver. Use double quotes `"\n"` instead of single `'\n'`when replacing

Comment: yes ! you are right " double quotes was the solution !! :) But what it works online with double quotes?

Comment: Can you make this statement a bit more clear:  "But what it works online with double quotes?"  ?

Comment: But why it works online with double quotes?